# How to calculate employees working hours in sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, time, sql-server-2017

My company business hour is 7:30 to 18 and 13:00 to 15:00 is lunch time.
Important part is about lunch time that should not calculate as working time of employee at all.

- So imagine employee start working at 8:30 and exit at 15:00 so the time of 4:30 hours should be calculate for him. actually I want to remove lunch time from attendance time of employee in different situations:

[image]

My fields are all  in Time(7) format in Sql.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @SelimYildiz I calculate datediff(enter-exit)-datediff(13:00,15:00)
but I need to remove overlap time of lunch time from working time

Comment: Can you share the code which you have written to solve this problem? What's the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I need code to remove lunch time from attendancetime to calculate Working time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach in SQL Server. It fundamentally splits each person's shift into two - Pre-Lunch and Post-Lunch. When a shift goes into (or past) lunch, it uses the lunch times as the bounds instead.

I've also written it in bits (e.g., CTE, sub-query, etc) so you can run those individually to see what they do. It is likely you'll need to update it for your own database structures etc.

```
-- Data setup

CREATE TABLE #WorkLog (WorkDate date, StartTime time, EndTime time, StartLunch time, EndLunch time)

INSERT INTO #WorkLog (WorkDate, StartTime, EndTime, StartLunch, EndLunch) VALUES
('2020-09-01', '07:30', '18:00', '13:00', '15:00'),
('2020-09-02', '12:00', '15:00', '13:00', '15:00'),
('2020-09-03', '15:00', '18:00', '13:00', '15:00'),
('2020-09-04', '08:30', '15:00', '13:00', '15:00')

SELECT * FROM #WorkLog

------

-- Find times worked

; WITH PreLunchTimes AS
        (SELECT WorkDate,
                StartTime AS StartTime,
                CASE WHEN EndTime < StartLunch THEN EndTime ELSE StartLunch END AS EndTime
        FROM    #WorkLog
        WHERE   StartTime < StartLunch
        ),
    PostLunchTimes AS
        (SELECT WorkDate,
                CASE WHEN StartTime > EndLunch THEN StartTime ELSE EndLunch END AS StartTime,
                EndTime AS EndTime
        FROM    #WorkLog
        WHERE   EndTime > EndLunch
        )
SELECT  WorkDate, SUM(Elapsed_Mins) AS Total_Work_Mins, CAST(DATEADD(minute, SUM(Elapsed_Mins), 0) AS time) AS Total_work_time
FROM   (SELECT  WorkDate, DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS Elapsed_Mins
        FROM    PreLunchTimes
            UNION ALL
        SELECT  WorkDate, DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, EndTime) AS Elapsed_Mins
        FROM    PostLunchTimes
        ) AS A
GROUP BY WorkDate
ORDER BY WorkDate
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f25888f445b528e4da859c955309deea)

Issues:

- If you have shifts go past midnight, you'll need to add in appropriate code to deal with that.
- If *all* lunchtimes are 13:00 to 15:00, then you can just set these as variables (e.g., @LunchStart and @LunchEnd) rather than storing them in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this code to solve your problem

```
TimeSpan? ActualTime = obj.ExitTime - obj.EnterTime;
string[] LunchTime = obj.lunchTimeString.Split('-');
TimeSpan ActualLunchTime = TimeSpan.Parse(LunchTime[1].Trim()) - TimeSpan.Parse(LunchTime[0].Trim());
TimeSpan WorkingHours = TimeSpan.Parse(ActualTime.ToString().Trim()) - TimeSpan.Parse(ActualLunchTime.ToString().Trim());
```

In this code what I have done is:

1. You have to calculate the actual time including lunch time.
2. Your 2nd problem is lunch time it's format is (13:00 - 15:00). So, I can't take time(7) in sql so take it as varchar and then split it with '-'.
3. Then calculate the total lunch time with it.
4. Lastly subtract actual time and actual lunch time you will get your working hours.

Answer (score 0):

Alas you forgot to give us the structure of you database table. Are your EnterTime and ExitTime full DateTimes, or do you have a WorkDay, and a TimeOfDay on that day where the Employee Starts and Stops working?

Besides that you forgot to give us your table structure, I don't know how you communicate with your database, whether you use entity framework, or talk traditional SQL, and which SQL dialect you speak. Some dialects have the possibility to do DateTime calculations, others don't.

The comment of MadReflection is wise: if you can change your database, consider to remember the start and stop DateTime of the shift before lunch and the start / stop DateTime of the shift after lunch. This way you are prepared for future changes like different lunch times per Employee, or even per day of the Employee. If you think in DateTime for Enter and Exit, you can even let an Employee start working on New Year's eve and stop working in a different year.

Luckily, you don't have to let the DataBase calculate the lunchTime, because you can do the lunch time calculations locally. This is faster than letting the database management system calculate them and transfer the results from the DBMS to your local process.

Locally the lunch time calculations will just a subtraction of two longs, which is way faster than the code needed to transfer the data.

So we can't give you the SQL. You'll have to write the procedure to fetch the data yourself.

You'll need a method to fetch the EnterTime / ExitTime per Employee during a period of time, or maybe for all Employees. The result is something like:

```
class WorkingTimes
{
     public EmployeeInformation Employee {get; set;}

     public DateTime EnterTime {get; set;}
     public DateTime ExitTime {get; set;}
}
```

And methods to get this information per employee, or for all employees:

```
IEnumerable<WorkingTimes> FetchWorkingTimes(DateTime beginPeriod, DateTime endPeriod)
{
    ...
}

IEnumerable<WorkingTimes> FetchWorkingTimes(int employeeId, 
     DateTime beginPeriod, DateTime endPeriod)
{
    ...
}
```

To convert the fetched data in the format that you want, a simple LINQ method will do:

```
class WorkingTimeExt
{
    // TODO: if needed: add employee information

    public System.DayOfWeek DayOfWeek => this.EnterTime.DayOfWeek;
    public DateTime EnterTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime ExitTime {get; set;}

    public DateTime StartLunch {get; set;}
    public DateTime StopLunch {get; set;}
    public string Lunch => String.Format("...", this.StartLunch, this.StopLunch);

    public TimeSpan WorkingTime => this.StartLunch - this.EnterTime
                                 + this.ExitTime - this.StopLunch;
}
```

The calculation of WorkingTime is fast, it is the addition of some longs.

```
TimeSpan defaultLunchStart = TimeSpan.FromHours(13.00);
TimeSpan defaultLunchEnd = TimeSpan.FromHours(15.00);

IEnumerable<WorkingTimes> fetchedWorkingTimes = ...
IEnumerable<WorkingTimesExt> result = fetchedWorkingTimes
    .Select(fetchedTimes => new WorkingTimesExt
    {
         EnterTime = fetchedWorkingTimes.EnterTime,
         ExitTime = fetchedWorkingTimes.ExitTime,
         StartLunchTime = fetchedWorkingTime.EnterTime.Date + defaultLunchStart,
         StopLunchTime = fetchedWorkingTime.ExitTime.Data + defaultLunchStop,
    });
```

If you need to do this regularly, consider to create an extension method for it:

```
IEnumerable<WorkingTimesExt> result = ToExtendedWorkingTimes(
     this IEnumerable<WorkingTimes> source,
     TimeSpan timeLunchStart,
     TimeSpan timeLunchStop)
{
    return source.Select(fetchedTimes => new WorkingTimesExt
    {
         EnterTime = fetchedWorkingTimes.EnterTime,
         ExitTime = fetchedWorkingTimes.ExitTime,
         StartLunchTime = fetchedWorkingTime.EnterTime.Date + timeLunchStart,
         StopLunchTime = fetchedWorkingTime.ExitTime.Data + timeLunchStop,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another worked option with time worked converted to HH:MM format:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (dow VARCHAR(10), workstart TIME, workend TIME);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
('Monday', '7:30', '18:00'),
('Tuesday', '12:00', '15:00'),
('Wednesday', '15:00', '18:00'),
('Thursday', '8:30', '15:00');

WITH 
lunch(lunchstart, lunchend) AS (
SELECT CAST('13:00' AS TIME), CAST('15:00' AS TIME)
),
attendances AS (
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN workstart <= lunchstart THEN
     CASE WHEN workend <= lunchstart THEN
          DATEDIFF(minute, workstart, workend)
     ELSE
          DATEDIFF(minute, workstart, lunchstart)
     END
ELSE 0 END --AS morning_shift
+
CASE WHEN workend >= lunchend THEN
     CASE WHEN workstart >= lunchend THEN
          DATEDIFF(minute, workstart, workend)
     ELSE
          DATEDIFF(minute, lunchend, workend)
     END
ELSE 0 END --AS afternoon_shift 
AS total_mins 
FROM t1, lunch
)
SELECT *, FORMAT(total_mins / 60 * 100 + total_mins % 60, '#:0#') AS hhmm 
FROM attendances;
```